# Integer literal overflows when stored into 'Int' error

Tags: ios, swift

I get an error message, when I archive my project. How to fix it?

```
static let litersPerUSGallon = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa:UInt64(3785411784), exponent: -9, isNegative:false)
static let litersPerImperialGallon = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa:UInt64(454609), exponent: -5, isNegative:false)
static let kilometersPerStatuteMile = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa:UInt64(1609344), exponent: -6, isNegative:false)
static let kilometersPerLiterToMilesPerUSGallon = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa:UInt64(2352145833), exponent: -9, isNegative:false)
static let kilometersPerLiterToMilesPerImperialGallon = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa:UInt64(2737067636), exponent: -9, isNegative:false)
static let litersPer100KilometersToMilesPer10KUSGallon = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa:UInt64(425170068027), exponent: -10, isNegative:false)
static let litersPer100KilometersToMilesPer10KImperialGallon = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa:UInt64(353982300885), exponent: -10, isNegative:false)
```

[image]

Comment: This error pops up only when I archiving project to be sent to the appstore

Comment: See also here for a more general answer related to this error message: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329459/integer-literal-overflows-when-stored-into-int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During archiving, the code is compiled for all architectures which are
configured in the build settings under "Architectures".

On the 32-bit iOS platforms, `Int` is a 32-bit signed integer which cannot 
hold the value `3785411784`. It seems that the compiler cannot infer
the type of the integer literal as `UInt64` correctly in this context.

But the solution is simple: Just omit the `UInt64()` constructor.
The type of the `mantissa:` parameter is `UInt64`, and the integer 
literal is correctly taken as a 64-bit number, even on 32-bit platforms.

```
NSDecimalNumber(mantissa:3785411784, exponent: -9, isNegative:false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the type to `UInt64` by using the code below:

```
let myInt:UInt64 = 12345
```