# Integer literal overflows when stored into 'Int'

Tags: swift

Xcode is complaining about the following line:

```
let primary = UInt32(0x8BC34AFF)
```

With this error message:

```
Integer literal '2344831743' overflows when stored into 'Int'
```

I see that it overflows a signed integer, but I intentionally used UInt32. My question is more "how can this be" instead of "how can I fix it".

Comment: This error can be very insidious - it can be dependent on the target platform, so your program can compile and run fine for iPhone 6, and then when you switch the simulator to iPhone 5 this error pops up and prevents compilation! Fortunately the answer below fixes the problem, and explains the 32-bit vs. 64-bit background.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`UInt32(0x8BC34AFF)` creates a `UInt32` by calling an initializer.  The `UInt32` initializer you are calling is:

```
init(_ v: Int)
```

The problem is that on a 32-bit device (iPhone5 and earlier), type `Int` is 32-bits.  So, the constant you are passing `0x8BC34AFF` overflows the `Int` that you are passing to the initializer of `UInt32`.

The way to have this work on both 32-bit and 64-bit devices is to cast the integer literal to the type:

```
let primary = 0x8BC34AFF as UInt32
```

Alternatively, declare the variable to be `UInt32` and just assign the constant:

```
let primary:UInt32 = 0x8BC34AFF
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My code built and worked fine until just now, when for some reason it suddenly wasn't fine. I haven't changed devices or anything, although this may be the first time I've tried building for this device with Xcode 9.

Comment: I had to do `1489064651000 as UInt64`

Answer (score 1):

You may also run into this issue if you have not selected any device or simulator before trying to run unit tests. (in that case default `Generic iOS Device` is selected). I have received this error for some integer values in unit test classes.