# Integer literal '4294967295' overflows when stored into 'Int'

Tags: swift

I get an error message, when I archive my project. How to fix it? The error is in line number 2.

```
func random() -> CGFloat{
    return CGFloat(CGFloat(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}

func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer literal overflows when stored into 'Int' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402819/integer-literal-overflows-when-stored-into-int-error)

Comment: You must be building for a 32-bit platform, as that number is outside the range of a signed 32 bit integer (which `Int` will be on 32-bit hardware).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler considers `0xFFFFFFFF` as an integer literal, but the
value is too large for a (signed) `Int` on a 32-bit platform. 
Choosing the (unsigned) `UInt32` instead solves the problem:

```
func random() -> CGFloat{
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
}
```